# Creating separate objects for a new user in Django

Tags: django

I want to create a set of "event" objects that belongs to a new user, when said users is created. The way I thought of doing this, was to overwrite Django's User classes save method.

My User class is just an extension of Django's user class, with three different options that define the type of the object:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from events.models import Event

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='myuser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    isA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isC = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None and self.isA:
            event = Event.objects.create(name="Event", rank="A", owner=self.user)
            subEvent = Event.objects.create(name="Sub Event", rank="AA", owner=self.user, parent=event)
```

For my Event class, I've used a Django package called "mptt": https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/. This was chosen, because it's an easy way to implement tree structures. The model is shown below:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Event(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)


    class MPTTMeta:
        order_indertion_by = ['rank']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

Doing it this way, I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "owner_id" of relation "events_event" does  not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "events_event" ("name", "rank", "owner_id", "par...
```

Any thoughts on how to fix the error, or think of another way to do the same thing? One thing I thought of was to add a regular method into the class say tree:

```
def tree(self):
    if self.pk is None and self.isA:
        event = Event.objects.create(name="Event", rank="A", owner=self.user)
        subEvent = Event.objects.create(name="Sub Event", rank="AA", owner=self.user, parent=event)
```

But I'm unsure how I would add this to the admin site.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you code is being called before the User object is saved.

If you class `MyUser` is actually extending the Django User model (in your code it is not) you save should look something like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_create = self.pk is None
    user = super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_create and self.isA:
        event = Event.objects.create(name="Event", rank="A", owner=user)
        subEvent = Event.objects.create(name="Sub Event", rank="AA", owner=user, parent=event)
```

`pk` and `id` can generally be interchanged, so if `self.pk is None` it also means `self.id is None`.